# NSPredicate isKindOfClass only works for [myObject class] not for [MyClass class]

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, nspredicate

Why is it that `[MyClass class]` fails to find the objects of the class I want in a predicate whereas `[myObject class]` works? See code example below. I want to be able to find objects of type MyClass in a set without needing to have a spurious instance of the class available.

```
MyClass* myObject = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

This doesn't work...

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isMemberOfClass: %@", [MyClass class]];
NSArray* predicateResults = [mySet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate].allObjects;
```

This does work...

```
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isMemberOfClass: %@", [myObject class]];
NSArray* predicateResults = [mySet filteredSetUsingPredicate:predicate].allObjects;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A predicate like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isMemberOfClass: %@", [MyClass class]]
```

actually works. It returns *exactly the same predicate* as the (documented)

```
[NSComparisonPredicate
    predicateWithLeftExpression:[NSExpression expressionForEvaluatedObject]
                rightExpression:[NSExpression expressionForConstantValue:[MyClass class]]
                 customSelector:@selector(isMemberOfClass:)]
```

The problem in your case could be that `isMemberOfClass:`
compares for class *equality*, so this would not match objects which are members
of a subclass of `MyClass`.

This could happen if `MyClass` is a class cluster and `myObject` is an instance
of a concrete subclass. For example:

```
NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:"hello world"];
Class c1 = [NSString class];   //  NSString
Class c2 = [myString class];   //  __NSCFString

BOOL b1 = [myString isMemberOfClass:c1]; // NO
BOOL b2 = [myString isMemberOfClass:c2]; // YES
```

In that case `[myObject class]` and `[MyClass class]` are different, which would explain
why one predicate works and the other predicate does not work.

The following code uses `isKindOfClass:` instead and produces the expected result:

```
NSArray *array = @[@"123", @456, [NSArray array]];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [NSNumber class]];
NSArray* predicateResults = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", predicateResults);
//  Output: ( 456 )
```

Comment: Just found the `predicateWithLeftExpression:rightExpression:customSelector:` in the docs when I saw your edit :). Still, this is not well documented for the `predicateWithFormat:` method.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis: Yes, unfortunately the "Predicate Programming Guide" is not covering all aspects. Another important topic which is almost undocumented is "SUBQUERY".

Comment: "In that case [myObject class] and [MyClass class] are different" Why would `[myObject class]` and `[MyClass class]` be different?

Comment: @newacct: If `MyClass` is a class cluster and `myObject` an instance of a concrete subclass. I have rewritten the answer to make (hopefully) clear what I mean. It still has to be confirmed by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Not strictly speaking an answer to your question (see MartinR excellent answer), but an alternative to the (IMO) under documented `predicateWithFormat:` method:

You could use `predicateWithBlock:` to create your `NSPredicate`, like so:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
    return [evaluatedObject isKindOfClass:[myClass class]];
}];
```

This should work fine.

Comment: @Andy With NSFetchRequest or simple NSManagedObjects collections ?

Comment: @klefevre with NSManagedObjects. This question is not about NSFetchRequest at all...