# Get all objects of an NSArray that are of a specified class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I have an array with objects of potentially different classes, such as:

```
NSArray *multiClassArray = @[@"foo", @42, @"bar"];
```

I want to get a new array containing all of the objects of `multiClassArray` whose class is a member of, say, `NSString`.

Is there a more elegant approach than looping through each item of `multiClassArray`, checking its class, and appropriately storing it in a new array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using `NSArray`'s instance methods:

- `- indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`
- `- objectsAtIndexes:`

The following code is an example of how to create an array that contains all of the string objects of the original array.

```
NSArray *multiClassArray = @[@"foo", @42, @"bar"];

NSIndexSet *idxSetOfStrings = [multiClassArray indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    return [obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]];
}];

NSArray *arrayOfStrings = [multiClassArray objectsAtIndexes:idxSetOfStrings];
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution

```
NSArray *multiClassArray = @[@"foo", @42, @"bar"];
NSPredicate* predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self isKindOfClass: %@", [NSString class]];
NSArray* arrayOfStrings = [multiClassArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

(Yes, such a predicate does work. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/18378811/1187415.)